# Как плагин scrollTofixed заставить срабатывать еще раз, когда страница подгрузилась?

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно реализовать [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/). Единственное, тот блок, который в примере `<li id="left">` у меня с подгрузкой при прокрутке.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.left_side').scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: $('.wrap_header').outerHeight() + 10,
            limit: $('.seenScroll').offset().top - $('.left_side').outerHeight() - 10,
            zIndex: 999,
        });
});
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при догрузке нового контента на страницу, мой код вызывался снова

Comment: Ну вызвать колбек функцию после догрузки. Как выглядит ваша догрузка?

Comment: @Telion , у меня идет запрос к Rest Api и ответ сохраняется в data, ну а потом при помощи vue я помещаю данные на страницу